# DAO pattern in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios5, datasource

How do you implement the access to the data in Objective-C?

I was googling DAO + Objective-C and there not so much results, so I believe that's not the way to accomplish the access to the data.

My data is stored in sqlite database. I have some experience with UITableView datasource and delegates, but I would like to have my "DAOs".

Should I create a protocol - delegate to access to my data? If so, should my delegate methods be instance or class methods? etc?

Do you know any good resource about creating classes to access data in iOS?

Comment: Look into the CoreData framework

Comment: I wrote an app that skipped the Objective C layer and used the sqlite c API. I used an Objective-C singleton that managed the database and all the read/write operations to it. I set it up with a protocol - delegate. And then each controller that needed to use the singleton set itself as the delegate object.

Comment: Are you familiar with DAO in any other language? DAO in Objective-C wouldn't really be any different than doing it in Java, for example.

Comment: Here is an example DAO with Core Data: https://github.com/j4n0/jobsket/tree/master/sources/main/coredata/dao The Dao class contains generic methods, tailored for specific entities in the subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of choices:

> 1) Use the c wrapper provided by sqlite3. If you're good at C or if you read carefully this could be a good option.  http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html
>   This is a pretty good book about sqlite and has a short chapter about using sqlite in iOS: 
>   The Definitive Guide to SQLite, Second Edition
>   By: Grant Allen; Mike Owens
>   Publisher: Apress
>   Pub. Date: November 30, 2010
>   Print ISBN: 978-1-4302-3225-4
>   Web ISBN: 1-4302-3225-0
>   Pages in Print Edition: 367
>
> 2) Use Core Data. This is an especially good choice if you don't need to access a sqlite database directly (perform sql queries, etc). http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html
>
> 3) Use a database wrapper like FMDB (get it from github)